# Do many anime play the main theme during the final battle?

Tags: tropes, theme-song

While watching an anime series with a friend, he pointed out that "all anime play their theme song during the final fight." Now, I doubt it's "all", but sure enough, the main theme song of *Digimon Tamers* and the (first) OP of *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood* play during the final epic clash in their respective series. (And I'm sure there are many other examples.)

Do most anime do this? Is there a reason for it (as opposed to just playing a new epic piece)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tvtropes call that a [Last Episode Theme Reprise](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LastEpisodeThemeReprise), and mentions that it is used in video games as well:

> Since it's standard practice to make a Theme Song as awesome as
>   possible, said theme likes to find its way into a privileged position
>   in the final battle. At The Climax of the series, when things are at
>   their most epic, the theme gets played over the show itself. Typically
>   we'll get to hear the verses not played in the opening, and sometimes
>   the whole song is strung together for once.
>
> The opening or closing theme can be used. Often this serves as an
>   ultimate Theme Music Power-Up. Often it serves in this capacity for
>   the show itself. The creators seem to be claiming their own Crowning
>   Moment of Awesome with this music.
>
> This is also common in Video Games, the most common being a reprisal
>   or orchestral version of the main theme over the final dungeon or
>   ending sequences.

I would say that it is at least not uncommon, since the page has an extensive list of titles that use this trope, to name a few:

- Neon Genesis Evangelion
- Dragonball GT
- FMA
- Eureka Seven
- Witchblade

and many others. As for *Is there a reason for it (as opposed to just playing a new epic piece)*, usually there isn't. If it is significant, however, it rather seems to be the [Title Theme Drop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitleThemeDrop) trope;

Comment: If i remembered correctly Soul eater did this as well.

Comment: Hmm.. that tropes page also suggests [Theme Music Power-Up](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThemeMusicPowerUp) as a reason. Which I guess makes sense; the theme song in the finale always tends to give me goosebumps (in a good series, of course).